# EmberJS: The right way to use a page multiple times

Tags: ember.js, architecture

I've got a product index page that I need to use multiple times:

```
# All products
product-index -> product

# Categorized products
category -> subcategory -> product-index -> product

# A persons products
profile -> product-index -> product
```

As you can see the `product-index` and `product` routes are nested in multiple situations. In all cases each view is a fullscreen page and from all pages the user can navigate back until the root page.

My idea is to configure the router like this:

```
// router.js
this.resource( "products", function() {
  this.route( "product", { path: "/:product_id" } ); 
} );

this.resource( "categories", function() {
  this.route( "category", { path: "/:category_id" }, function(){
    this.resource( "products", function() {
      this.route( "product", { path: "/:product_id" } ); 
    } );
  } );
} );

this.route( "profile", function() {
  this.resource( "products", function() {
    this.route( "product", { path: "/:product_id" } ); 
  } );
} );
```

But I'm wondering if above is the right way to do this, or that maybe I should always link to the same product-index page and filter the products. (eg `products?cat=bags` or `products?user=12`)

Also, when I'm going to use the first solution I need to be able to re-use my `products controller`, but I'm not sure how yet.

For now I'd like to know What the right thing is to do, ember-wise, and why?

Comment: I think the second approach is the better way to do things. A single product route/controller/index page should exist and you should display data based on filters. And since the product controller is reusable, it kind of shows that ember expect only a single route for a given name.

Comment: Most probably you would have defined your controller as : App.ProductController= Ember.ObjectController.extend() .... Ember uses naming conventions to link a controller and a route to a template. This convention can be overridden but what it means is you can only have one controller, template and route for a given route name.

Comment: @PranavaSheoran That indeed sounds right. I'm using EmberCLI, so all controllers are named like the way they are structured in directories/files because the using of ES6, I guess. Would this cause problems if I'd used the first solution?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to explore Ember-cli yet so I might not be the right person to answer. But in Ember.js, your controllers should follow the convention. The javascript filename containing the controller can have any name but the controller declaration has to follow the convention unless you explicitly change that. What I mean is if your route is product then Ember expects the controller to be defined as App.ProductController= Ember.ObjectController.extend(). But you can place this in a file called abc.js and include that in HTML. So the filename doesn't matter.

Comment: @tim i dont think your current route setup will work as a resource create a new namespace while naming stuff. Every time you write this.resource( "products"... it will override the last declaration. My suggestion is to make the products and products route separate. Or use differnt names for the products resouce like products, category-products, profile-products. You can reuse the controller code by just creating a base products controller and make the other controllers extend from it.